# linux process lookup/process library?

Tags: bash, process

[This is a script](https://github.com/holtzilya2008/scripts/tree/master/cleanproc) (I am not the author) that basically runs `ps -eo comm` every second, display and log processes not in whitelist.

I want to modify it to make it easier to be able to identify and distinguish processes(e.g. process systemd is a system process for linux: system(required)), and mark each process system/trusted/safe/unknown/malicious. I think it would be best to use something like a process library website.

For windows, there is something like [this](https://www.processlibrary.com). This website provides nice little details for system processes and common windows processes.

Is there a website like this for linux processes?

Comment: I'm not sure that script is suitable for security monitoring. If I'm running a shell script, `ps -eo comm` would output `bash`. If that's added to my whitelist, every shell script in my system would be whitelisted. If you're looking for an intrusion detection mechanism, take a look at something like [AIDE - Advanced Intrusion Detection Environment](https://aide.github.io/).

Comment: you're right. thought this way could at least detect little keyloggers and such but i think aide is what i am looking for.